# How to cancel rounding big numbers at Zabbix graphs?

Tags: zabbix

I have a graph that displays the count of files in a directory. I need the exact number of files in the graph but I cannot find that feature in the Zabbix configuration.

Any suggestions?

[image: See Y axis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found answer.

We need to change ZBX_UNITS_ROUNDOFF_UPPER_LIMIT in /include/defines.inc.php - It is responsible for number of digits after comma, when value is greater than roundoff threshold. By default it is 2.